# Update document content in Alfresco using Apache Chemistry Asynchronously

Tags: asynchronous, alfresco, cmis, opencmis

I am using OpenCMIS 1.1.0 to execute CRUD operations on an Alfresco Content Repository. Using the examples provided [here](https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/) I am able to execute all CRUD operations on both folders and documents.

Now I want to execute these operations (esp. create and update) **asynchronously**. Using this excellent SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291411/asynchronous-cmis-client-download-or-upload-several-files-in-parallel-with-open) I can **create** documents asynchronously. However, OpenCMIS AsyncSession class does not provide an *updateContentStream* method.

Is there some way I can use OpenCMIS API to update document content asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

All operations that require a change token are not available in `AsyncSession` because the outcome would not be predicable if two operations on the same object would be scheduled.
But you can add your own Callable. Cast your `AsyncSession` object to `AbstractExecutorServiceAsyncSession` and call `submit` with your own Callable object. Here you can do whatever you want.

Such a Callable class could look like this:

```
public class SetContentStreamCallable extends SessionCallable<ObjectId> {
    private Document doc;
    private ContentStream contentStream;
    private boolean overwrite;

    public SetContentStreamCallable(Session session, Document doc, ContentStream contentStream, boolean overwrite) {
        super(session);
        this.doc = doc;
        this.contentStream = contentStream;
        this.overwrite = overwrite;
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectId call() throws Exception {
        return doc.setContentStream(contentStream, overwrite, false);
    }
}
```

But keep in mind not to run two tasks on the same document!